Why is my pvalue for chisquared test so high?
I am sampling from values = [0, 1] with prob = [.25, .75].
I obtain 25019 zeros and 74981 ones. Yet, by chisquared test results in the following:
statistic=0.0196, pvalue=0.889
This doesn't seem to match my intuition.
Maybe this is a reason to use fisher exact test? Should I be using KS test for freqeuncies?
Here is my code
N = 100000
values = [np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[.25, .75]) for _ in range(N)]
one_count = sum(values)
zero_count = len(values) - one_count
test_stat = (N*.75 - one_count)**2/(N*.75) + (N*.25 - zero_count)**2/(N*.25)
print(test_stat, 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(test_stat, 1))


You might need to explain why it doesn't match your intuition.

What is your null hypothesis?

Under the null hypothesis, the p-value is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$.  Why does 0.889 strike you as unintuitive?

Now that I write my hypothesis out... proportion of 0 is 25% and proportion of 1 is 75%.... I think this result makes sense.... right?

Whether you meant to do this or not, your null hypothesis is that there is a 3:1 ratio. Indeed, there is such a 3:1 ratio at the population level, and your empirical data show roughly a 3:1 ratio. Thus, your p-value is rather large, as we would anticipate when the null hypothesis is true.

+1. A tiny little bit more precisely: under the null hypothesis (which is true here, as you write), we don't necessarily anticipate a large p value. Rather, under the null, p is uniformly distributed on [0,1], so it's equally likely to be small as to be large. In contrast, under the alternative hypothesis, p is more likely to be small, which is why we don't accept the null if p is large. Look at "The dance of the p values" on YouTube.

It's not clear where your doubt arises.
The standard error of your proportion (either one) under $H_0$  is $\sqrt{\frac{1\times 3}{4\times 4 \times 100000}}\approx 0.00137$.
Meanwhile the "error" in your proportion (absolute difference from the null value) is only $\frac{19}{100000}=0.00019$, way less than the standard error. Which is to say, your observed proportion is about one seventh of a standard error away from the hypothesized value.
So you should expect a high p-value! One well above $0.5$, indeed fairly close to $1$.

A quick eyeball test when hypothesized proportions are middling (between say 0.25 and 0.75 or even a little wider) is to use the upper bound margin of error (approximately twice the upper bound on the standard error), that is $1/\sqrt{n}$ $-$ if that's not smaller than the observed difference from the null, you shouldn't expect significance.
Mentally this is simple enough to do a rough calculation: $100,000=10 \times 10,000$ so the square root is roughly $3 \times 100$; the reciprocal is then roughly $0.3/100$ or $0.003$. Your difference is way smaller, so your p-value should be larger than $5\%$.
Such quick mental approximations are invaluable both for understanding what your results should look like and for identifying the inevitable errors that can crop up. It's a useful, or rather I'd say essential habit to have a collection of such quick approximations ("reasonableness checks" as one of my old lecturers more fittingly called them). The accuracy of my work as a student improved dramatically when I learned to make a habit of developing and using them and it's paid dividends ever since. It's interesting to discover - once you have a collection of approximations and rules of thumb all in place - how often one can glance at a set of numbers and say something like "obviously this won't reject" or "that's roughly 5 standard errors away", or occasionally "well that statistic can't be right".

Thank you, for some reason I though the null hypothesis of the chi-squared was that proportions don't equal the expected values. It seems that the null is that the observed proportion do equal the expected values.

I'm glad that you have sorted out the issue. The expected values are computed under the null. One thing to notice is that the chi-squared statistic you used is the square of the usual z-statistic for a single proportion. Its value is bigger when the standardized deviation in count (or proportion) from expected is larger, and you are therefore rejecting for large values of the statistic (i.e. when the proportions are not close to expected).
